# Нужно сделать скриншот расписания на сайте при помощи selenium

Tags: python, python-3.x, веб-программирование, парсер, selenium

Есть задача сделать скриншот расписания занятий на сайте, пыталась сделать через размер, но кол-во пар не всегда совпадает c размерами заданных по умолчанию, тем более не всегда влезает в окно скриншота все предметы. Пробовала с driver.find_element_by_class_name но он там скринит только первый элемент, а при 
driver.find_elements_by_class_name возвращает список, поэтому нельзя сделать скрин.
Вот сайт: http://almetpt.ru/2020/site/schedulegroups/0/1/2020-03-17
Подскажите, как можно сделать скрин для каждой группы отдельно)

Comment: Если эти расписания есть в вёрстке сайта, а не подгружаются джаваскриптом, то можете парсить страничку без селениума и скриншотов. С помощью библиотек `requests` и `re`. Сейчас глянул - нужный вам `div` имеет класс `d-inline-block card w-100`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если Вам нужен именно скриншот через selenium то можно так:

```py
from selenium import webdriver
if __name__ == '__main__':
    driver = webdriver.Firefox()
    driver.get('http://almetpt.ru/2020/site/schedulegroups/0/1/2020-03-17')
    # driver.save_screenshot("screenshot.png")
    element = driver.find_element_by_class_name('card-columns')
    element.screenshot("screenshot_full.png")
    driver.close()
```

> Закоментированная строка будет возвращать только видимую часть экрана

UPD: на коментарий:

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

if __name__ == '__main__':
    driver = webdriver.Firefox()
    driver.get('http://almetpt.ru/2020/site/schedulegroups/0/1/2020-03-17')
    # driver.save_screenshot("screenshot.png")

    element = driver.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, 'd-inline-block')

    for elem in element:
        # title = elem.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, 'card-header').text
        title = elem.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, 'card-header').get_attribute('data-id')
        elem.screenshot(f'./{title}.png')

    driver.close()
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

> Дополнил вариантом, который, как мне кажется, для бота, будет предпочтительней. В нем убрано само окно `webdriver`, ну и учтено пожелание на счет `data-id` в качестве названий скриншотов.

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver import FirefoxOptions
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

if __name__ == '__main__':
    options = FirefoxOptions()
    options.headless = True
    driver = webdriver.Firefox(options=options)

    driver.get('http://almetpt.ru/2020/site/schedulegroups/0/1/2020-03-17')

    element = driver.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, 'd-inline-block')

    for elem in element:
        title = elem.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, 'card-header').get_attribute('data-id')
        elem.screenshot(f'./{title}.png')

    driver.close()
```

Comment: Тк так то я скринить умею, у меня тоже получается один скрин делать, но мне не один общий скрин нужен, а по все группам отдельно, типа для одной гр одна фотка для другой другая фотка, как то в цикле надо зделать

Comment: @ВалерияЛебедева, обновил ответ

Comment: А как вот в этой части   
for elem in element:
        title = elem.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, 'card-header').text
писать в title не содержимое класса, а data_id, это уникальный id для каждой группы
Пробовала делать и пл class_name и по id ничего не получается

Comment: @ВалерияЛебедева, а Вы можете уточнить конечную задачу, которую Вы хотите решить с помощью Вашего кода?

Comment: Я бота делаю, который будет отправлять расписание человеку той группы в котором он состоит, на сайте у каждой группы свои id который и указан в data_id, чтобы можно было идентифицировать к какой группе относится скрин я и хочу называть скрин этим самым id, и отправлять ее пользователю

Comment: @ВалерияЛебедева дополнил ответ

Comment: @ВалерияЛебедева, ну в общем еще раз дополнил.

Comment: Ой спасибо большое, все дальше сама, почти уже закончила

Comment: @ВалерияЛебедева, лучшее спасибо, это принятый ответ ))).